# Control xvoice+ with Tasker?

Tags: tasker

Can it be done?

I want to enable it only when no cell radio (WiFi only)

Dev said state is controlled in "sharedpreferences"

Comment: Mind to give some more details? What's "xvoice+"? Is it an app? In user-space? Does it offer Tasker support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over at the [XDA Developers Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-xvoiceplus-voice-xposed-t2598889) where the dev and others talk and problem solve for this module of Xposed Framework, your answer is there is no a way for tasker to enable and disabled the functionality of XVoice+.

I could describe for you an indirect way to achieve what you are looking for through simulating taps and swipes, if you're interested. If you are please post the phone you're using, Android Version, Tasker Version, Xposed Modules and Tasker Plugins you have installed.

If my answer solves your problem please don't forget to mark it ask the answer as I'm trying to build up rep as I'm new.